# Array To List? Angular - Spring

Tags: java, spring, angular

I'm trying to make a post request but I'm getting a strange error.

> No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.List

clients,accounts and transactions are normal arrays (typescript doesn't have list) but this should work i guess.

Do I really need to get Client[],etc... and then convert to list in the controller? doesn't make much sense.

Code:

Request

```
createEnvironment(environment,clients,accounts,transactions) {
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set("environment", environment)
  .set("clients", clients)
  .set("accounts", accounts)
  .set("transactions",transactions)
  .set("isCloned", "false");

console.log(params);

return this._http.post<any>(RequestProperties.baseUrl + "/environment/create", params, this.options);
}
```

Spring

```
 @PostMapping("/environment/create")
public boolean createEnvironment(Environment environment, List<Client> clients, List<Account> accounts,
                                 List<Transaction> transactions,boolean isCloned) {
    environmentService.createEnvironment(environment,clients,accounts,transactions, isCloned);
    return true;
}
```

edit:

Well, even with Client[],etc.. I get

> No primary or default constructor found for class [com.myproject.models.Client;

Comment: Do you have a no-arg constructor on Client? If not, try adding one to see if that helps

Comment: yes I have. The problem is with JSON

Comment: The exception you are getting typically deals with Java - either being the constructor is not proper or there is a modifier set incorrectly. I will have to follow this to see how it was resolved for my own curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `@RequestBody` annotation before your method parameter that is meant to be deserialized from JSON. Given there is only one body in your request, you should wrap all of your objects in one DTO object. Also, dont pass your objects into an `HttpParams` object, but in your POST body.